# What's the drupal way to define global constants?

Tags: drupal

I'm creating a custom "glue" module for my site, and I want to define a path to another site as a global constant. Is there some drupal way to do it beyond putting a define() statement at the top of my module?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [variable_get](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7) and [variable_set](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7).

Comment: But variable_get/set will be deprecated from Drupal 8. Is it still recommended to use them?

Comment: Upgrading Drupal 7 Variables to Drupal 8 Configuration - https://www.drupal.org/node/1667896

Answer (score 3):

If the glue module is really just for one site and it's no problem if it's hardcoded, by all means hardcode it.

A lot of constants are set in Drupal core's modules: http://api.drupal.org/api/constants/7

If you want a more flexible solution use a table with a single row and put it in there, and expose an interface to the admin to change that the value of that single row.

Comment: why worry about tables and single rows? use variable_set & variable_get which is exactly that :)

Comment: In retrospect: the table with a single row is a bad alternative to variable_set and variable_get.